# Having issues with illegal characters in file path

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program in VB.NET which loops through a file with some file paths in it to perform an action on. The file paths in this file are each on a line, and i'm looping through the file like:

```
Dim FileContents As String
FileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\File.txt")

Dim FileSplit As String()
FileSplit = FileContents.Split(vbCrLf)

For Each ThisLine In FileSplit

    Dim FileModified As Date
    FileModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(ThisLine)

    'Do something here

Next
```

**Contents of File.txt is:**

```
Y:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\MakeShadowCopy\FileInfo.vb
Y:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\MakeShadowCopy\FindFiles.vb
Y:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\MakeShadowCopy\MakeShadowCopy.sln
Y:\Users\localadmin\Desktop\MakeShadowCopy\MakeShadowCopy.v12.suo
```

The loop works fine, but it is throwing an exception on the line with GetLastWriteTime() on it, saying that the path contains illegal characters, but it is just a normal string with a file path in it.

If anyone has any ideas, or know how to escape the string going into GetLastWriteTime() that would be much appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: Contents of `C:\File.txt`?

Comment: Are you able to manually open that file?

Comment: Have posted contents of File.txt

Comment: Yes, am able to open all of the ones above and the program is running with administrator privileges

Comment: Try to open that file with an editor capable to show white spaces likes TABs. The list above doesn't seem to contain VISIBLE illegal chars so, perhaps you have something hidden there

Comment: Thats interesting steve, I've opened the File.txt in Sublime text and it kind of looks like there is something at the end of each line, but this might just be the line break itself?

Comment: Well, the line break should be remove by the Split, but perhaps you should add a Console.WriteLine(ThisLine) inside the loop to check if the split  is occuring correctly

Comment: Just wondering: the .NET API reference doesn't seem to list a String.Split(String) method or corresponding extension method. Are you sure it does what you expect it to do? I recommend checking the result array elements to see if it really properly removed the CR and LF characters.

Comment: Yeah, thanks steve I tried that and it looks like there is an extra line break being sneeky in there, Ill try and remove it. Wormbo, thanks for the suggestion but I use String.Split(StringToSplit) all the time and never had any issues. But thanks though

Comment: Try `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the lines in your file are not correctly vbCrLf terminated.
If this is the case the Split cannot divide correctly your input in lines and you end up with the whole text passed to the GetLastWriteTime. 
Instead of using ReadAllText you could use ReadAllLines and let the work to split the lines to the Framework that knows how to handle the file line break and carriage return codes.

```
For Each ThisLine In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\file.txt")
    Dim FileModified As Date
    FileModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(ThisLine.Trim())
Next
```

Also add a Trim to the ThisLine variable to remove some unseen character added erroneusly to the line

Comment: Thanks for this everyone, it was just the way I was handling my line breaks. All working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. Use `For` instead of `For Each` and ensure that you're getting exception on the very first iteration. If not, you may have issues with one specific file path. Check out iteration variable value if that is the case.
2. Open the file in a hex editor and ensure that each line is terminating properly. You might have either CR (10) or LF(13) character at the end but not both as normal in Windows.